# Condition based on matched text on the current page in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi is it possible to have a certain condition in RAILS that will check if a particular HTML text exist?

Approach like this (BUT IN CAPYBARA):

```
find("a", :text => "MATCHED TEXT")
```

I want it to do not in testing.

For example I have a text `"HELLO"` in current page

```
<b>HELLO WORLD</b>
```

And i want to put a condition like this:

```
<% if current_page?(question_path) && request.path.include?('HELLO') %>

  <b>GOT IT <b/>

<% else %>

<% end %>
```

But the code above doesn't work, it just checks whether `HELLO` is inside the path itself. It will be satisfied if the route is `http://localhost:3000/HELLO` . But I want to check not in the path but inside the rendered page.

Comment: use hpricot to find inside html https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, just assign a random variable with the `HELLO WORLD` string, then compare it elsewhere:

```
<% random_string = 'HELLO WORLD' %>
<b><%= random_string %>
<% if current_page?(question_path) && random_string.include?('HELLO') %>
  <b>GOT IT<b/>
<% else %>
  ...
<% end %>
```